# ¿Cómo trabajar con listas en Python?

Tags: python, lista, archivo

Estoy intentando empezar a trabajar con Python y no entiendo lo que pasa con mi código. Mi intención es leer un archivo que tiene muchos datos, cargarlo en una variable y luego manejar esos datos como si fuesen números (que de hecho se supone, lo son).

Para eso estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
archivo = open('/home/juanito/Doctorado/Mediciones/2-1/02c.txt','rb') 
lineas = archivo.readlines()
print lineas
for i in range(10000):
        if int(lineas[i])>5: 
            for a in range(430):
                acum[a]=int(acum[a])+int(lineas[i+a-1])
            i=i+430
            pulsos=int(pulsos)+1
```

El error lo tira en la línea 5:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

se ve que hay algún elemento vacío, o que no puede convertir a enteros los valores que tiene. Con el print que hago antes del for visualizo mi variable y lo que me muestra son los valores numéricos que yo necesito, pero precedidos por un \t.

Ejemplo de las 4 primeras filas archivo txt:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   2   2   0   1   0   0   3   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   2   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   3   2   1   0   3   0   1   0   2   1   1   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   0   2   0   2   1   0   3   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   2   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   2   0   0   0   1   1   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   1   3   0   3   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   3   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Se que la pregunta es muy básica, pero busqué un poco y no encontré la respuesta, así que sí me pueden orientar, ¡se los agradeceré!

Comment: Muestra un ejemplo del contenido del archivo .txt

Comment: Estas son las primeras 2 lineas del txt
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 2 2 0 1 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 3 2 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 2 0 2 1 0 3 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añadelo alli, ademas de darle un formato adecuado, por ejemplo yo no se en donde termina la primera linea y comienza la segunda.

Comment: Naju aparentemente intentas leer un csv que usa tabulaciones como separador. En tal caso debes separar cada columna usando '\t' y eliminar saltos de línea.Mírate el módulo [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Para poderte ayudar es necesario que añadas la muestra del csv en el cuerpo de la pregunta para que se mantenga el formato como comenta eyllanesc (usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/129513/edit)) y que expliques que salida esperas obtener y cual es la idea del código, no termino de entender la idea del algoritmo ( `if int(lineas[i])>5`, `i=i+430`, ...).

Comment: ¿estas seguro que tu archivo tiene diez mil lineas? range(10000)

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas! Estoy leyendo el módulo csv, seguramente ahí esté la respuesta.

Comment: El archivo tiene 50000 líneas. 
Lo que quiero hacer es acumular cada uno de los 430 valores siguientes a un número mayor que 5. O sea, el dato que me interesa es el vector de 430 posiciones donde la primera tiene la suma de todos los lugares mayores a 5 la segunda de todos los lugares inmediatamente posteriores y así hasta n+430. Sí hay algún número mayor a 5 entre n y n+430 no me importa, lo sumo al vector igual que sí no hubiese aparecido un >5.
Voy a seguir leyendo el módulo, lo que me falta es saber como separar los tabs y que siga levantando valores igual cuando encuentra un /n

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usas `readlines()` lo que recibes es una lista de líneas, no de números.

Iterando por esa lista, obtendrás una línea de cada vez, no un número. 
Si quieres iterar por cada número de la línea, divide ésta usando `split()` (si no pones argumento a esta función, usará como separador cualquier espacio "tipo blanco", lo que incluye tabuladores o retornos de carro).

Así que para obtener los números individuales el bucle sería:

```
for linea in lineas:
    for dato in linea.split():
        n = int(dato)
```

En cada iteración de este bucle, `n` tomaría un valor de cada uno de los enteros de esa línea.

No obstante, con este esquema es difícil implementar eso de "los 430 siguientes números, si n>5", sencillamente porque quizás los siguientes 430 estén repartidos entre esta línea y la siguiente.

Por tanto sería mucho mejor leer el fichero completo en una sola cadena, en lugar de leerlo por líneas como tú has hecho. Para ello usarás `read()` en lugar de `readlines()`. Una vez leído puedes usar igualmente `split()` sobre el contenido completo, para separarlo en números individuales.

Esto simplifica el algoritmo:

```
archivo = open('/home/juanito/Doctorado/Mediciones/2-1/02c.txt','rb') 
datos = [int(dato) for dato in archivo.read().split()]
```

Ahora ya tienes en `datos` una lista de enteros que son todos los números del archivo, sin estar estructurados en líneas. A partir de aquí puedes seguir tú, pues yo no acabo de entender el objetivo final y los 430 esos que mencionas.

Comment: Muchas gracias abulafia! Ya había resuelto mi problema, pero volví a stackoverflow porque tenía uno nuevo. Es que tengo un problema raíz y es que no termino de entender el manejo de csv.
¡Pero tu explicación fue tan clara que ayudó con mi problema de hoy también! :D

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar `pandas` para leer tu archivo csv, acá puedes definir facilmente el separador `\t`, y como las columnas no tienen nombre lo defines sin encabezado.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('02c.txt', sep='\t', header=None)
```

Luego de leerlo, puedes realizar cualquier operacion de columnas, filas o convertirlo en una matriz de numpy para cualquier cosa que quieras hacer.